# Dynamically naming and exporting MAT files

Tags: matlab, save

I've tried to search stackoverflow for a solution, but the cases I found differ slightly from what I'm trying to do, so I thought I'd ask.

I have a loop in MATLAB, which for every iteration, a large matrix is computed. I want to save each matrix as a separate MAT file, however each file needs to be named according to its position in loop. For example: matrix1, matrix2,...

The method I'm using to save my data (which seemed different from the few examples I found) is the following (where matrix is the generated matrix and matrix1 is the filename to be saved for the matrix corresponding to i = 1)

```
 save matrix1 matrix;
```

I've seen something similar to

```
 save ['matrix', i] matrix;
```

But I can't seem to remember the exact syntax.

Sorry if the question is very basic, a simple nod in the right direction for this type of saving would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [functional form](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/command-vs-function-syntax.html) of `save`:

```
save(['matrix', int2str(i)], 'matrix');
```

Answer (score -4):

Here's my nod:

```
eval(['save matrix' num2str(i) ' matrix;']);
```

Good luck! :)

Comment: It seems to have worked! However it is saving all the program information rather than just the matrix I want. Do you know how to recitify this small issue? :)

Comment: -1: There's really no need for `eval`. In fact, `eval` is [best avoided](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/)

Comment: I see thanks! By any chance is there a similar syntax to load such files?

Comment: Never mind, figured it out. Thanks to you both for the help!